# sqlite union all optimization

Tags: sql, sqlite, union-all

I have a sqlite DB query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    origin,
    destination,
    weight,
    rate,
    0 as group
    from groupAZones, groupARates
    where
    tms = groupZone

union all

SELECT
    origin,
    destination,
    weight,
    rate,
    1 as group
    from groupBZones, groupBRates
    where
    tms = groupZone

    union all

SELECT
    origin,
    destination,
    weight,
    rate,
    2 as group
    from groupCZones, groupCRates
    where
    tms = groupZone

    union all

SELECT
    origin,
    destination,
    weight,
    rate,
    3 as group
    from groupDZones, groupDRates
    where
    tms = groupZone
```

Is there a good way to optimize a query like this?  I'm trying to create a simple view that combines these 4 tables.  With this used as the view query, queries into the view are taking about 13 secs.

I tried creating indexes for the 4 tables but it didn't seem to help.

I'm kind of a novice when it comes to SQL, I know enough to do the simple things but I'm still learning the advanced tricks.

Any pointers or info would be helpful.

Comment: About how much data are you dealing with?

Comment: If I build a table using the same query it works out to about 4.5 million records and around 125 MB on disk.

Comment: Show the output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` for this query.

Comment: CL that command actually let me to discover that two of my indexes were not being used!  After fixing the indexes the query is very fast now.  Thanks for helping me out!  I gave you an up vote for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CL pointed out that I should run the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` command.  This led to the discovery that two of the 4 indexes were not being used.

Thanks CL!

I'm still wondering if there is a better way to do that query, but for now it's doing what I need it to do.